# Building boost libraries with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, boost, codeblocks

Is there a way to build boost libraries without having Visual Studio installed? I tried to follow installation on: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/more/getting_started/windows.html and while in command prompt I've typed bootstrap.bat, I'm getting:

[image]

AFAIC cl is a VS compiler, but I do not have VS installed nor do I want to have it. I'm using Code::Blocks and GCC 4.7.1 and I want to build this library for this toolset, not for VS. Anyone?

Comment: You're probably going to want to specify `--toolchain=xxxx` (see documentation)

Comment: It *should* be build-capable with either a gcc under cygwin, , or *maybe* the Windows SDK (currently v7.1 last time I checked). Essentially all the tools except the whiz-bang IDE from VS are in the SDK. I've not tried it, but since it isn't VS-solution-file-based, I see no reason it couldn't be made to work.

Comment: You can definitely build it for mingw. You just have to set up the build properly with the necessary parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [A beginner's quick reference for setting up Boost with Code::Blocks in Windows](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef):

Bootstrap.bat assumes you are using msvc compiler, to use Gcc, type

> bootstrap.bat gcc